# How to use bootstrap tabs with dynamic data coming from database in php while loop

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, bootstrap-4

I want to use bootstrap tabs dynamically but I can't figure out how.
I basically need to get the name/id of the current tab and pass it into a PHP variable to then use in mysql `WHERE` clause to determine what data to show for that tab.

I can see this on the Bootstrap documentation -

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
e.target // newly activated tab
e.relatedTarget // previous active tab
})
```

BUT it really doesn't help me much with my actual code.

My code works like so ->

- I get the tab titles from a `SELECT` query and a PHP while loop
- I then use a different `SELECT` query with a `WHERE` clause that I need to be like -

  ```
  WHERE tab= $currenttab
  ```

  to generate the info to be shown for each tab in a PHP while loop

**UPDATE - i've realised that what I need to know is how to use ajax with the above piece of code from bootstrap to POST a jquery variable to a php variable ?? **

Comment: Show your effort to implement `$.post`.

Comment: I currently have this - 

`$(document).ready(function(){
            $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
                var x = $(e.target).text();
                console.log(x);
                
                $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url:'contacts_1.php',
                data:{'activeTab' : x},
                success:function(result){
                    $('body').html(result);
                }
`
                
                });
                });
       });`

Comment: I can now get the clicked on tab printed to a post varable - 
`<?php
if( isset($_POST['activeTab'])){
            $currenttab = $_POST['activeTab'];
            
            echo $currenttab;
        }
?>`
However, it is only printing the first tab clicked on after the page is refreshed. Meaning I have to manually refresh the page and click a new tab for it's ID to be posted.

Comment: Please read the duplicate, then try some more, then edit your question to show your best attempt (please don't write question details as comments).

Comment: If you no longer need support, you are authorized to retract your question.

Comment: I have read the duplicate but it doesn't help me with my specific problem.

Comment: It seems your question has fundamentally changed.  Perhaps scrap this one and ask a new, fresh, minimal question